# How to use case statement with forEach in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach, angular6

I want to select product in app.html from **typesFurniture**, in the uploadFiles() function to execute the product that I've selected, but i can't make it work. Help me please!

I've tryed with forEach and case statement but it didn't work. Don't know why...

i want to add images when i select one of my products through the dropdown list, my products are in array typesFurniture. But my problem here is i don't know to target selected product from dropdown list and then paste this code

```
const fileToUpload = this.files; 
const filesIdx = _.range(fileToUpload.length); 
_.each(filesIdx, (idx) => { 
this.upload = new Upload(fileToUpload[idx]); this.uploadService.uploadFile(this.upload);
```

**app.ts**

```
export class DodavanjeSlikaComponent {
  typesFurniture = ["Kuhinje", "Klizni ormari", "Ormari", "Radni stolovi", "Stolovi", "Cipelari", "TV Komode", "Police", "Paravani"];

  files: FileList;
  upload: Upload;

  constructor(private uploadService: UploadService) { }

  handleFiles(event) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
  }

  uploadFiles() {
    /* this have to include!
    const fileToUpload = this.files;
      const filesIdx = _.range(fileToUpload.length);
      _.each(filesIdx, (idx) => {
       this.upload = new Upload(fileToUpload[idx]);
       this.uploadService.uploadFile(this.upload);
 */

    // why this does not work, it won't execute the check that I've selected

    this.typesFurniture.forEach(i => {
      const fileToUpload = this.files;
      const filesIdx = _.range(fileToUpload.length);

      switch (i) {
        case "Kuhinje":
          _.each(filesIdx, (idx) => {
            this.upload = new Upload(fileToUpload[idx]);
            this.uploadService.uploadFile(this.upload);
          });
          break;

        case "Klizni ormari":
          _.each(filesIdx, (idx) => {
            this.upload = new Upload(fileToUpload[idx]);
            this.uploadService.uploadFile2(this.upload);
          });
          break;
      }
    })

  }

}
```

**app.html**

```
<div id="dodavanje-proizvoda">
  <div class="dodavanje-kocka">
    <div class="vrsta">
      <p>Izaberite vrstu proizvoda:</p>
      <select>
        <option *ngFor="let furniture of typesFurniture">{{furniture}}</option>
      </select>     
    </div>
    <div class="vrsta2">
      <input type="file" (change)="handleFiles($event)" multiple>
    </div>
    <div class="vrsta3">
      <input type="submit" value="Dodajte sliku" (click)="uploadFiles()">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the difference between uploadFile() and uploadFile2() ? I would expect only one uploadFile() function and then pass in the differences as a parameter so the switch statement is not needed. Or have the typesFurniture array also contain the correct method.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean?

Do you get a compiler error?

Do you get a runtime error?

Do you get unexpected behavior with no error?

Comment: There is no errors, but it won't  execute the product that I've selected. uploadFile() upload data to specific firebase path and uploadFile2() upload data to other firebase path

Comment: So, you get no errors. I guess that means that you are getting unexpected behavior. Please tell us what the expected behavior is, and how the actual behavior differs from the expected behavior. BTW, "execute the product" may mean something specific to you, but I can't figure out what that's supposed to mean.

Comment: i want to add images when i select one of my products through the dropdown list, my products are in array typesFurniture.  But my problem here is i don't know to target selected product from dropdown list and then paste this code ----->  const fileToUpload = this.files;
      const filesIdx = _.range(fileToUpload.length);
      _.each(filesIdx, (idx) => {
       this.upload = new Upload(fileToUpload[idx]);
       this.uploadService.uploadFile(this.upload);